# Is there somehow i can rotate button in python tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-button

```
Open_app = Button(window, bg = '#1E9099', text = "Open Google", fg = 'White'
,command = open_chrome,highlightthickness=0,bd=0, width = 10, height = 2)

Open_app2 = Button(window, bg = '#D53A33', text = "Open VScode", fg = 'White'
,command = open_code,highlightthickness=0,bd=0, width = 9, height = 6)

Open_app.configure(font = ('Valorant',8))
Open_app2.configure(font = ('Valorant',6))
```

I created 2 button and I want the Open_app2 button to rotate

Comment: No, you cannot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you cannot rotate a button. tkinter has no ability to rotate widgets.